# WHERE If condition is not met get all values including NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

Either get only those userIDs with the specified @Lastname or if @LastName = 'All' then get all userIDs even if they have NULL values as their LastName.

```
SELECT userID INTO #table 
FROM users 
WHERE LastName = CASE 
                 WHEN @LastName = 'All' THEN LastName 
                 ELSE @LastName END
```

The above query only returns those userIDs where the LastName is not NULL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another shorter form

`where @LastName  in ('All', LastName);`

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d7a58/9)

Answer (score 3):

Change your condition to this instead:

```
where (@LastName = 'All' and 1=1) or (LastName = @LastName)
```

The idea is that when `@LastName` = 'All' then your query should not have any filters. The 1=1 condition will be always true, and together with the other check should return all results. The other path the query can take is filtering by a specific Last Name, which should definitely exclude null values.

Update: THE 1=1 condition is redundant. You can rewrite the condition as:

```
where (@LastName = 'All') or (LastName = @LastName)
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d7a58/4)

Comment: Why do you use `1 =1` ? I belive only `where (@LastName = 'All' ) or (LastName = @LastName)` is sufficient

Comment: @Akhil Just realised its redundant, but I wasn't sure the query would work without it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT userID FROM users
WHERE
    CASE WHEN @LastName = 'All' THEN LastName = LastName
    ELSE LastName = @LastNam END
;
```

Comment: This gives me an error on = in `Lastname = Lastname`

Answer (score 0):

you can also try it-

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE IF(@lastname<>'all',lastname=@lastname,1=1);
```

In case @lastname contains multiple last name then you can use below query-

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE IF(@lastname<>'all',FIND_IN_SET(lastname,@lastname),1=1);
```