# MySQL Force 'WHERE' to show null when condition not met

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having problem linking 2 tables, where one's does not have value, it does not show. To simplify this, I create a temporary table to show:

**The Details**

```
ps_product table

product_id    name
     1      Product 1
     2      Product 2
     3      Product 3
```

that needs to link with another table to show the image path:

```
ps_product_details table

details_id  product_id    properties    value
     1          1       image_location  1.jpg
     2          1          width        10 cm
     3          1          height       5 cm
     4          2       image_location  2.jpg
     5          3          width        9 cm
     6          3          height       5 cm
```

As seen here I am able to join them with `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT * FROM ps_product
LEFT JOIN ps_product_details ON ps_product.id = ps_product_details.product_id
```

and the result is this:

```
product_id    name     details_id   product_id   properties       values
     1      Product 1      1            1       image_location     1.jpg
     1      Product 1      2            1            width         10 cm
     1      Product 1      3            1            height        5 cm
     2      Product 2      4            2        image_location    2.jpg
     3      Product 3      5            3            width         9 cm
     3      Product 3      6            3            height        5 cm
```

There is no problem until now.

**The Problem**

I did not want to show the `width` and `height` during the joining process, so what can I do id put `WHERE properties = 'image_location'`, but when I put it, it shows this:

```
product_id    name     details_id   product_id   properties       values
     1      Product 1      1            1       image_location     1.jpg
     2      Product 2      4            2       image_location     2.jpg
```

As seen here, the **Product 3 disappear** because there is no image for it, I did not want to show that product 3 does not exist, it only does not have images.

What I really want:

```
product_id    name     details_id   product_id   properties       values
     1      Product 1      1            1       image_location     1.jpg
     2      Product 2      4            2       image_location     2.jpg
     3      Product 3     null          3       image_location     null
```

The `details_id` and `values` could be null, because I don't know the value for it. but the `properties` I already know it is a `image_location`. In this way I can show no pictures instead of no products.

**What I have tried**

1. From [@shree.pat18](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2491900/shree-pat18) in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31000210/where-if-condition-is-not-met-get-all-values-including-null)

This is the query I implement from it:

```
SELECT * FROM ps_product
LEFT JOIN ps_product_details ON ps_product.id = ps_product_details.product_id
where (properties = 'image_location') or (properties = properties)
```

it just the same result as this query **earlier**:

```
SELECT * FROM ps_product
LEFT JOIN ps_product_details ON ps_product.id = ps_product_details.product_id
```

Is there are solution, and thank you for the time.

Comment: move the conditions in `where` clause to your `LEFT JOIN` clause. you will get your results as expected :)

Comment: thanks @SudiptaMondal for the solutions, and more faster responds. I appreciate that effort

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the condition in the `ON` clause instead of the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ps_product p
LEFT JOIN ps_product_details pd ON p.id = pd.product_id AND pd.properties = 'image_location'
```

and if you want to be real picky, you can `coalesce()` in the `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT p.product_id, p.name, pd.details_id, p.product_id, coalesce(pd.properties,'image_location') as properties, pd.values
FROM ps_product p
LEFT JOIN ps_product_details pd ON p.id = pd.product_id AND pd.properties = 'image_location'
```

Comment: wow the first one solved my case, i think I did not need complexity like `coalesce()` did, but the properties still null, which I definitely can handle inside my C# code when I call the stored procedure. Thanks for the solution and god bless america